# iTunes Connect: Your app has one or more issues

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am a bit frustrated because since yesterday i try to upload a new version of my Egg-Timer app to itunes connect. The upload itself works but after the upload finished i always get this email:

> Dear developer,
>   
>   We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "IsI Egg Timer". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>   
>   Invalid Signature - Code object is not signed at all. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
>   
>   Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>   
>   Regards,
>   
>   The App Store team

I already tried to change the provisioning profile in the build settings (build settings < code signing) with the same result. I downloaded a new profile, changed code signing identity to i phone developer, iOS distribution and iOS developer - always the same result.

Perhaps anyone can help me out.

Thx

Comment: Already tried this link? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH5-SW2

Comment: What should i try with this link? Should these problems not occur before the upload succeeds?

Comment: your provisioning profile will be usually checked while archiving the app, but distribution profile will checked on upload only and since Xcode 6 they have changed error checking and telling to us at end now.

Comment: but it would be nice if they would tell us what the problem is...

Comment: Have you created a distribution provisioning profile and a distribution certificate?

Comment: Couldn't be more clearer than this:

Invalid Signature - Code object is not signed at all. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear, you didnt sign your app before submitting into the App Store. So what you have to do is>

- Go to the Dev Portal and generate the distribution certificate.
- Apply this certificate to your project (If you are using the most recent Xcode version you may want to leave the *Automatic* option when choosing certificate)

And then you should be able to submit your app without any trouble into the app store.

Please follow these guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html

Hope it helps.